# What is the most comprehensive overview of methods that explain why an object detection network got a particular answer?

Tags: object-detection

There are methods like Grad-CAM. With them, you can look at a particular layer of the network and see how it activated for a specific input.

My question is about the methods with the purpose similar to Grad-CAM—to explain in general or in particular how the network came to such a result, but specific to object detection networks.

After searching for a while, I haven't found papers about such methods, therefore, I'm asking here.

Do such methods exist? If so, what is the most comprehensive overview of them?

Comment: are you looking for studies on explainable NNs? would it matter if you can't explain but still trust the outputs?

Comment: @Aksakalalmostsurelybinary, I've found this cluster of papers (arxiv.org/abs/1811.08011). I'm looking for similar things that explain why network has given a particular out, preferably without altering the initial network.

Comment: I tried to provide a tentative answer. This is a beatiful literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very interesting and recent literature.

I would suggest to take a look at?

**About Grad-Cam**

[I believe this is the first paper in Grad-Cam](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02391.pdf)

[An extension of Grad-Cam](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11063.pdf)

**Related Literature:**

[Deconvolution approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf)

[Another variant of the deconvolution approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806)

[Yet another convolution approach](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vedaldi/assets/pubs/mahendran16salient.pdf)

[Maximizing the response of units](http://www.dumitru.ca/files/publications/invariances_techreport.pdf)

[Directions of the input space that most affect the output](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/baehrens10a/baehrens10a.pdf)

[Region pertubation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06321)

[Representations combinations of lower level filters](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml09-ConvolutionalDeepBeliefNetworks.pdf)

[Sintetization of input images that cause high activation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.06579.pdf)

[Also Sintetization of input images that cause high activation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6034.pdf)

[Approximation of the surface decision](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04938)

[Approximation of the instantaneous gradients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02685)

[Detection of the neurons responsible for decisions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3f13/b3e10b48644c401a5041b682517bc875cdf4.pdf?_ga=2.104648832.1838003537.1581797387-1439606366.1563622701)

[Visual explanation via resambling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09641.pdf)

[Visual explanation by finding the regions responsible by the decision](http://nterpretable%20learning%20for%20self-driving%20carsby%20%20visualizing%20%20causal%20%20attention)

[Via influence function (robust statistics)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04730)

[Via sampling techniques](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/fastnc.pdf)

[Applied to text analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01444)